# How to figure out current DWU of a Data Warehouse using DMVs?

Tags: azure-synapse

Is it possible to figure out current DWU utilization (not the service plan) of an Azure Data Warehouse using Data Management Views?  If so, how?  Couldn't find any blogs on the subject

To clarify further, using Insights API to get at the value of current DWU is not working very well.  The real values are 20-30minutes delayed.  Using Insights API, my current DWU is consistently 0%, while 10mins ago it is 10%, 20mins ago it is 15% and 30mins ago it is showing 75%.  Azure portal is consistently showing high DWU utilization.  Looks like Insights API is lagging by a good amount

Answer (score 0):

You can read the blog below that shows you how to monitor the DWU for a database.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqldw/2016/03/18/how-to-determine-the-dwu-setting-for-a-sql-data-warehouse/

Comment: Thanks, but I meant current utilization of the database, not the "service tier" level. I'll update my question to make it clear